# Python removing list elements issue

Tags: python, list

How can I solve the following problem? I want to delete parentheses and commas.

```
output = [("apple",), ("orange",), ("banana",)]

desired output = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
```

Comment: Those are tuples of length one. Get the first element from each tuple in a `for` loop.

Comment: You can you single statement here like - `list(map(lambda x: x[0], output))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items inside the list are tuples, simply iterate over it and get the items inside those tuples:

```
print([item for tup in output for item in tup])
```

This solution will work if your tuples are like `[("apple","something-else"), ("orange",), ("banana",)]`

Since in your situation there is only one item, you can do the following as well:

```
print([tup[0] for tup in output])

print([x for x, in output])  # Thanks @timgeb for mentioning in comments.
print([x for [x] in output])
```

Comment: `[x for x, in output]` is my fav

Comment: @timgeb yours doesn't work and just returns the inital list of tuples. You need the ```[0]``` as in SorousH's second example.

Comment: @StevenThomas `[x for x, in output]` works. Did you miss the comma after the second `x`?

Comment: apoligies, I put the comma in the wrong place

Comment: @timgeb Great. I Added yours in the answer along with `[x for [x] in output]`. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
output = [("apple",), ("orange",), ("banana",)]

# this bit is not needed, but is how I would go about 
# learning about the structure of my data
>>> type(output) # find output type
list
>>> len(output) # find output length
3
>>>type(output[0]) # find output's element types
tuple

# this is how I would tackle the problem, assuming you
# want the data in a new list of just the strings
desiredOutput = [None] * len(output) # create empty list of same length
for i in range(0, len(output)): # loop over array
    desiredOutput[i] = output[i][0] # [0] needed to access the first element of each tuple

>>> print(desiredOutput)
['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
```

Comment: Although this works, I think this is overkill.

Comment: In what sense? I was trying to demonstrate how to work through an issue and find out how your data is stored.

Comment: I know your answer works perfectly and I didn't downvote yours. I just want to mention that there is no need to first get the `len` of the list, then create a list of "len" length items, then iterate over the actual list and fill the result list with `output[i][0]`. People say this is not a "pythonic" solution.

Comment: This is a fair comment. I shall update my answer to explain the first part is about troubleshooting and learning about how your data is arranged. As for the creating an empty array ```desiredOutput```, it looked to me as though the OP wanted a new array rather than just print the outputs as in your answer. I'm also not so familiar with the syntax in your answer. Does yours create the empty list first before iterating, or does it unpack the ```output``` array into temporary memory and then create a list of required length after, or does it append to a list on each iteration?

Comment: That's called a "list comprehension" and yes it will create a new list so you can either assign it to a new variable or pass it to print function to print it right away just like I did. [This](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is how it works.

Comment: That's it! I have come across it a few times, but couldn't remember what it was called. I didn't realise it didn't create any dummy variable ```i``` in the process which is good. I'm still not clear about whether it is appending as it goes along, or whether it knows about the length of the list to begin with though, as the example in your link suggests it is equivalent to the first example using append. I'm enquiring as I'm interested about performance for longer lists.

Comment: Yes list comprehensions are doing their jobs by appending values. This is why you can see "over-allocation/pre-allocation" behavior with them.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. In that case I think I still prefer my answer, and I'm quite glad any of my codes use my way rather than list comprehension (although I know that generally speaking for loops are inefficient, and I try to use numpy arrays or f2py wherever I can for intensive tasks). Thanks for taking the time to explain that to me though.